# Rewriting functions in java scripts

Tags: javascript

Just came across a funky function rewriting concept in Javascript.

```
var foo = function () {
    alert("Hello");
    foo = function () {alert("World !");};
};
foo();
foo();
```

In what situations are these helpfull and is there any other scripting language which support this kind of code ?

Fiddler link : http://jsfiddle.net/4t2Bh/

Comment: This is called [lazy function definition](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/04/27/the-russian-doll-principle-re-writing%C2%A0functions%C2%A0at%C2%A0runtime/#more-351), similar to lazy loading except that the variable happens to hold a function.

Comment: That just gives you a warning that variable is already defined and will just alert "Hello" http://jsbin.com/ocezar/1/edit

Comment: @elclanrs but call `foo()` a second time and see the alert says. It will not be hello.

Comment: It is helpful if you need to run a expensive lookup/check that will not change and you can make it so the following calls use the previously found data. Sort of like a getter type of pattern. http://jsfiddle.net/NHHFH/

Comment: I'd rather see a one-shot flag  (`if(!ran){ran=true; ...}`) than this self-rewriting code.

Comment: @elclanrs I ran previous code in Chrome > console, and it was working, both fiddler and js bin threw warnings. Updated with working code now.

Comment: This adds some complexity and the following code won't have the same behaviour than calling twice `foo`:
`var bar = foo; bar(); bar();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this idiom to initialize a LUT on the first call like this

```
var getBase32Value = function (dummy) {

    var base32Lut = {};
    var alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ234567";

    for(var i=0; i<alphabet.length; i+=1) {
        base32Lut[ alphabet[i] ] = i;
    }

    getBase32Value = function (v) {
        return base32Lut[ v ];
    }
    return base32Lut[ dummy ];
}
```